# How to parse nested parameters in a Clojure defn?

Tags: clojure

I was browsing some [Clojure source code](https://github.com/gtuckerkellogg/pairwise/blob/master/src/pairwise/core.cljs#L42) and came across this function:

```
(defn draw-mask [app-state [r c]]
  (let [x1 (+ 25 (* c 50))
        y1 (+ 25 (* r 50))]
    [:circle {:cx x1 :cy y1 :r 12 :fill "white"}]))
```

What I do not understand is how `[app-state [r c]]` is parsed. What would a typical data structure passed to this and how does defn parcel it out. Any references to this in the clojure docs would be appreciated, especially since [ClojureDocs.org was of no help on the subject](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defn).

Comment: Iirc, all destructing uses the `deconstruct` (or something like that) macro. It just turns it into calls to `first`, `rest`, and `nth` for lists, and delegates to accessors for maps. Just typical macro "magic".

Comment: The word for this is "destructuring" -- using that should help you find good documentation, such as http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring

Comment: ...frankly, I think that describing how destructuring works *in general* (which is how I read this) is too wide a scope to be a good StackOverflow question -- if you look at the destructuring page linked above, there's much more content than what an answer can reasonably cover!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `draw-mask` in your example takes two arguments.  The first is `app-state`, which is not used in your code, and the second can be one of several different types of data: values from a map, a string, a list, or most commonly, a vector.  You can see the different types here that can be used in `nthFrom` in the [clojure code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L915).

This is called sequential [destructuring](http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring), and as other comments above mention, it's a big topic.  However, for your case, this is how it works:

```
(draw-mask xyz [3 9])     ---> In draw-mask, r is 3, and c is 9.
(draw-mask xyz [3])       ---> In draw-mask, r is 3, and c is nil.
(draw-mask xyz [3 9 12])  ---> In draw-mask, r is 3, and c is 9 -- 12 is not bound
```

One clarification here:  whether or not a structure is `seqable?` is not the main criteria for being able to be destructured.  For example, a `set` is `seqable?` but cannot be destructured.  The main criteria for ***sequential*** destructuring (different from associative destructuring, using maps, which is not discussed here) is that `nth` must be supported on it. In [RT.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L915), you will see the list of possible types.  They are: `CharSequence`, a native Java array, `RandomAccess`, `Matcher`, `Map.Entry`, and `Sequential` (`Sequential` will cover the most common structures: list and vector).

Answer (score 3):

**Correction**

As [@Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41022925/1562315) points out, sequential destructuring requires `nth` to work: seqability is not enough.

---

This is a simple case of [sequential destructuring](http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_sequential_destructuring). Let's use a function that shows what's going on:

```
(defn foo [app-state [r c]]
 {:app-state app-state, :r r, :c c})
```

- The first argument, `app-state`, can be anything.
- The second argument, `[r c]`, must be something like a sequence that
  [`nth`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/nth) applies to. Then

  - `r` is its `first` element, and
  - `c` is its second.
- If the sequence isn't long enough, these yield `nil`.

Examples:

```
(foo 1 ())
;{:app-state 1, :r nil, :c nil}

(foo inc "hello, world!")
;{:app-state #<core$inc clojure.core$inc@32d23c2f>, :r \h, :c \e}

(foo :one [:two :three :four])
;{:app-state :one, :r :two, :c :three}

(foo  "Flubalub" (drop 5 (iterate #(* 10 %) 1)))
;{:app-state "Flubalub", :r 100000, :c 1000000}
```

But

```
(foo 99 #{1 2})
;java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: PersistentHashSet
; ...
```